# Access Google Sheets API from Java servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Google App Engine app, which accesses a spreadsheet from Google Drive by using the Google Sheets API. I have found an example from Google, which shows how to access the Calendar from Google app engine application: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-appengine-sample

I took that as a base and try to replace the Calendar call with the SpreadSheet call. In this example, the Calendar data is accessed by this code:

```
static Calendar loadCalendarClient() throws IOException {
String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getUserId();
Credential credential = newFlow().loadCredential(userId);
return new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
}
```

However, Sheets API does not provide any Sheets.Builder. Instead, from another example (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), I found that they use the following code:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
// TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)
```

So, the trick is to authorize the Sheets service with the credentials. I'm trying to merge these examples, but without success:

```
String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getUserId();
Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId); // the flow object which was used to create an OAuth flow
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("AppName");
credential.refreshToken();
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

After calling the service.getFeed method I receive an exception:

```
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: OK
Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>
Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>
Error 401
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Okay, right after 1 hours after asking a question, I can answer it by myself. This exception appears if you pass wrong credentials. Alternatively, if GAE engine has remembered your credentials and does not prompt you to enter the new ones ;-) Once I apply correct credentials, everything works!